# Windows: problem closing 32-bit consolle application

Tags: windows, memory, dll, unload

I am working on an application that when compiled in debug mode for Win32 (on a x64 machine), just before exiting, throws this exception:

[image: Error shown on application termination]

From what I was able to reconstruct, it seems that the offending line of code is this, in the xmemroy0.h header:

```
// If the following asserts, it likely means that we are performing
// an aligned delete on memory coming from an unaligned allocation.
_STL_ASSERT(_Ptr_user[-2] == _Big_allocation_sentinel, "invalid argument");
```

It seems that this happens when a dll of mine (which is part of the application) is unloaded by the SO. It doesn't seem to be a directly a problem of my software, but I fear I could be the indirect cause of the problem by not handling correctly the dll boilerplate code. For example I am doing nothing special to handle attachments/detachments in the dll. What seems wired to me is that the x64 version seems to work just fine.

Any clue from a senior system programmer that could point me in the right direction would be highly appreciated. I don't really know how to debug this, I am not an expert of the Windows internals.

Sincerely,

Comment: Did you check (with a debugger) where this code was called from?

Comment: I tried to with VS debugger. I was not so much able to really detect what is the caller. what I know is that it is something AFTER the last statement of my programs `return 0;`.

Comment: There are a number of reasons for this. Please create a  [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I was hoping for a listing of those possible causes, Í don't really know what to focus on in the reprex. However, creating a reprex is already a (time consuming and uncertain, in this case) bug solving strategy. Thank you!

Comment: Most likely, it occurs when deallocating some statics, but there might be other reasons, that's why I asked for a *MCVE*.